What is the correct way to use classes as dependencies(parameter check)?
Main goal here is mapping UI sent parameters to match my db tables.

Now call me crazy but this was working a second ago and now its not.
I have a  few classes and one function(in S_Sorting) here
class ScanSort(str, Enum):
    ASSET_NAME = "assetName"
     CREATED_AT = "createdAt"
    ...

class BaseSorting(BaseModel):
    sort_order: Annotated[SortOrder, Query(...)] = SortOrder.ASCENDING
...

class S_Sorting(BaseSorting):
    sort_by: Annotated[ScanSort, Query(...)] = ScanSort.CREATED_AT
...

  @staticmethod
    def scan_table_mapping(passed_param: str) -> str:
        mapping = {
            ...,
            "createdAt": "scans.created_at",
            ..
        }
        return mapping.get(passed_param, "scans.created_at")


that my function relies on for sorting my data(in a postgres db).

 def build_query(
            self,
            ...,
            sorting: S_Sorting,


sort_by_mapped = S_Sorting.scan_table_mapping(sorting.sort_by)

direction = asc if sorting.sort_order == SortOrder.ASCENDING else desc
        query = query.order_by(direction(text(sort_by_mapped)))


So if there is no sort parameter, then it default sorts according to S_Sorting , works fine.
Now when I pass in sort=createdAt it should sorting that mapped value.
However, this is the error I get:
{
   "detail": [
       {
           "type": "enum",
           "loc": [
               "query",
               "sort_by"
           ],
           "msg": "Input should be '..., 'createdAt' or 'updatedAt'",
           "input": " createdAt",
           "ctx": {
               "expected": "'..., 'createdAt' or 'updatedAt'"
           }
       }
   ]
}

I'm literally giving it what it expects. What am I doing wrong with classes as dependencies?

There's a leading space "input": " createdAt"

There was a leading space...Thank you.

The question is too generalised, still what I can think of is: giving you a basic and full idea of usage regarding the dependencies. But I'll use async in this case for better independent parallel process completion. You need to generate the query on your own for this code and input it where required..
You define sorting rules using classes, which specify the order (ascending or descending) and criteria (like date added or last played with). A function translates these criteria into a format the computer understands, making sure the data is sorted correctly.
When you send a sorting request via a web route, the code checks for any mistakes like extra spaces, follows the defined rules, and returns the sorted data. This ensures your toys (or data) are neatly organized according to your chosen criteria.
from enum import Enum
from pydantic import BaseModel, Query
from typing import Annotated

class SortOrder1(str, Enum):
    ASCENDING = "asc"
    DESCENDING = "desc"

class ScanSort1(str, Enum):
    ASSET_NAME = "assetName"
    CREATED_AT = "createdAt"
    UPDATED_AT = "updatedAt"

class BaseSorting2(BaseModel):
    sort_order: Annotated[SortOrder1, Query(sample)] = SortOrder1.ASCENDING

class S1Sorting(BaseSorting):
    sort_by: Annotated[ScanSort, Query(...)] = ScanSort.CREATED_AT

    @staticmethod
    def check_table_mapping(passed_param):
        mapping = {
            "assetName": "scans.asset_name",
            "createdAt": "scans.created_at",
            "updatedAt": "scans.updated_at",
            }
        return mapping.get(passed_param, "scans.created_at")

def generate_query(self, sorting: S1Sorting):
    sort_by_mapped = S1Sorting.scan_table_mapping(sorting.sort_by)
    direction = asc if sorting.sort_order == SortOrder.ASCENDING else desc
    query = query.order_by(direction(text(sort_by_mapped)))
    return query

from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/items/")
def get_items(sorting: S1Sorting = Depends()):
    query = generate_query(sorting=sorting)
    return {"query": str(query)}

from fastapi import Request

@app.middleware("http")
async def strip_whitespace_middleware(request: Request, call_next):
    query_params = request.query_params._dict
    stripped_query_params = {k: v.strip() for k, v in     query_params.items()}
    request._query_params = stripped_query_params
    response = await call_next(request)
    return response

It helps organize data in a database by sorting it based on specific rules. Think of it like organizing your toy box by different categories such as color, type, or size.
